# can't call part of $_SESSION as variable

Tags: php, arrays, session

i'm trying to call certain parts of my $_POST form info from a previous page we start on index.php, send the form in POST form over to contact.php, which then will email it off( that parts working though). what im having trouble is taking the post information putting it back into a session variable and sending it back to index.php. i can to do a foreach command for $_SESSION['pos'], and print out each variable one after the other, but its leaving me unable to put in things before their info, like name: and email:

contact.php

```
session_start(); //start session
$_SESSION['pos'] = $_POST; // turn $_POST info into $_session info
```

index.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['pos'])){ //check to see if session info is set
    echo '<div class="alert alert-info">'; //create alert div
    $item = $_SESSION['pos']; //change session into variable for easier indexing?
    echo "Name: ". $item[0]."<br><br>"; //echo line 0 from array
    echo "Email: ". $item['1']."<br><br>"; //echo line 1 from array
    echo "</div>"; //close alert div
}
session_unset();//unset session variables to avoid re-using them.
```

i really wish i knew how to correctly search for the answers i'm looking for. i feel horrible for having to resort to asking how to do this, because i'm sure the answers out there.

Comment: ohhhh so its pulling the key names from POST as well instead of just numbering them.... $calling the orginal post key fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your form fields are named `0` and `1` etc, `Name: " . $item[0]` is incorrect and should be something like `Name: " . $item['name']` where the array key corresponds to the form input's name attribute.

Also, you might want to avoid calling `session_unset()` as this will clear ALL session data which you might not want.

Instead, you can use [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) on the relevant data:

```
// unset the POST data from the session, leave everything else
unset($_SESSION['pos']);
```

If you had:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
```

Your code might then look like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['pos'])){ //check to see if session info is set
    echo '<div class="alert alert-info">'; //create alert div
    $item = $_SESSION['pos']; //change session into variable for easier indexing?
    echo "Name: ". $item['name']."<br><br>"; //echo line 0 from array
    echo "Email: ". $item['email']."<br><br>"; //echo line 1 from array
    echo "</div>"; //close alert div

    unset($_SESSION['pos']); // remove post data from session
}
```